# How to talk to primary schooler about home schooling

Tags: primary-schooler, parents, united-kingdom

I had been having a lot of financial difficulty and it has lead to me choose between options e.g. to send or not to send as he study in a elite school because of school system in UK we preffered to have him in a private school.

I had tried to take some holiday before but it did not sit with him well and he was representing his emotion though drawings and I fear I will destory his confidence if I change his school but I do not have other option than to homeschool, whilst homeschooling is very new idea to me I am afarid of his habit as he can keep on watching 24 hours if not stopped.

I wanted to know what is the best route and if I take homeschooling option how should I talk to my son, should I tell him why (money issue) or something else

Comment: Your question is about your son, but your concerns seem to be more with other adults.  Is it the son you need help talking to, or the adults?  Ideally, mom and dad would be talking to the son together, after deciding together.  What's preventing that from happening?

Comment: @WayneConrad I m breadwinner of the house, things were good but It has been struggling yrs after covid, my wife isn't much on same page as me as she think it will break our son confidence as getting admission in grammar school (passing test etc) isn't easy. I think if I cannot sustain earning I cannot afford the school. I wanna sit down with my son as he does miss school, activities and friends and I have seen a cheerful side of him in school as well so I am confused if I killing my son confidence

Comment: I feel for you, you are in a tough spot.  I want to caution you that your present question might not be a good fit for this site (it's not clear to me what you're asking); you may get feedback and guidance to that effect.  I would suggest that the parents need to figure things out first before talking to your son together, as a team.  What your son needs most, no matter where he goes to school, is love and support from two parents who are working together.

Comment: @WayneConrad I have updated the question

Comment: I am finding this question confusing. What sort of school is your child currently in? Are they happy there? Is this a fee paying school you want to remove them from due to cost, and homeschool is your only option? What is wrong with the local primary schools? Is your wife concerned about the 11+ exam? What previously made your child upset so he was expressing himself with negative drawings? How old is your child?

Comment: @RDavies It is a grammar school, yes he is happy in it. I have heard state school isn't good as I migrated here so private school was only option, my wife is concered about my son as he doesn't talk easily and school was only place he was ok with in coming back to his self after his granny died. so wife think he might go back to being closed and not open etc. My concern is finance as I keep loosing jobs.

Comment: @localhost you should probably edit your question to include more of this information. 
Your son is happy in his current (fee paying) school, but you need to move him due to finances. 
I'd encourage investigating your local schools (you say primary school in the tags of your question, but grammar school is usually 'high school') as not all of them are bad. OFSTED (which has been in the press a lot recently) inspects schools and the reports are available to the public. You can also look up your local homeschooling groups for advice on homeschooling.

Comment: From you other posts, I understand you have a number of challenges with communication and other aspects of parenting. This is likely to make home schooling rather difficult and could impact your son's confidence more than moving him to a state school.

Home schooling would require you to be able to manage your work time, and plan your lessons, and deliver them effectively, being able to switch between your breadwinner and parent roles, and a new teacher role.

Comment: As one of the comments stated, look at various state schools in your area. If they are anything like Scotland, you will find some state schools outperform private schools

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to talking to primary schoolers about home schooling, it's important to approach the conversation with empathy and openness. Depending on the child's age and personality, they may have a range of emotions and concerns about the situation, so it's essential to listen to them and validate their feelings.

One helpful strategy is to frame home schooling as a positive opportunity for growth and learning. Talk to your child about how this experience will allow them to develop new skills and knowledge, and encourage them to share their own ideas and goals for the coming weeks and months.

It's also important to provide structure and routine to help your child feel secure and supported during this time. Work with them to create a schedule that balances academic work, play, and relaxation, and be flexible as needed to accommodate their individual needs and interests.

In addition to these practical strategies, it's crucial to prioritize open communication and emotional support. Encourage your child to ask questions, express their feelings, and share their experiences, and be there to listen and provide comfort as needed.

Overall, talking to primary schoolers about home schooling requires patience, compassion, and a willingness to adapt to their individual needs and perspectives. By approaching the conversation with an open mind and a focus on positive growth, you can help your child navigate this challenging time with confidence and resilience.

[Moreparenting.com](https://moreparenting.com/)

Comment: this answer sounds GPT-generated and the link has nothing to do with the content.